# getting the sub-document with the document in mongoose.findOne

Tags: mongoose, subdocument

First, my code is working well, but i don t know if doing the right thing.
I have a parent model Units with this schema

```
{
  info: {...},
  chapters: {_id: string, ...}
}
```

the chapter schema is like this:

```
{
  info: {...},
  content:  string
}
```

now in the client if i am editing the a chapter, and want to put the changes to the database, i do it like this

```
Units.findOne({'chapters._id': chapter_id}) //this query will return the parent unit
.then(unit=>{ //is there a way to have the chapter with unit here??
  const chapter = unit.chapters.find(chapter=> chapter._id === chapter_id)
 //seems like duplicated. i already found the unit based on the chapter_id
  //after that i update the chapter
})
```

that's it, I wish there is a way to return the chapter in the first query

Comment: i'm not mongo expert , but i think the answer is no. there is a `parent()` function in mongoose, but you can't get child(sub document) directly. instead you can replace `unit.chapters.find(chapter=> chapter._id === chapter_id)` with `unit.chapters.id(chapter_id)` which is lot more cleaner.

Comment: also you can use `Units.findOne({'chapters._id': '5d6bbabba001071b8099fe1b'}, {_id: 0, chapters: {$elemMatch: {_id: "5d6bbabba001071b8099fe1b"}}})` this will filter chapters, so there will be only 1 chapter in Units. (the found chapter)

Comment: yes i was using ```$elemMtch``` but i think that it will search all chapters, and i dont want that. ```chapters.find()``` will stop in the first match